# Java IntelliJ error Cannot access for scala class

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Intellij shows me an error:

> Cannot access eu.teldoc.xyz.ApiConnector

code:

```
return ApiConnector$.MODULE$.apply(l, p);
```

but for example mvn clean compile works fine..

scala code for this lib:

```
object ApiConnector {

  def apply(l: String, p: String): ApiConnector
```

any idea how to fix IntelliJ there ?

thanks!

Comment: What IDE version do you use? This works for me in [2022.1.2 Preview](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2022.1+latest+builds) version. If for you the problem with this version remains, file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample isolated project tat reproduces this.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Community Edition) Build #IC-221.5591.52, built on May 10, 2022

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to File -> invalidate caches/Restart in Intellij ?

Comment: yrs, did not help